# Adding packed bytes/words using MMX instructions

Tags: x86, simd, mmx

So let's say that we have two registers that contain the following hexadecimal
values: `AB0890C2`, `4598EE50`. What would be the result of adding them using MMX
instructions:

```
a. for packed byte
b. for packed word
```

Assuming saturation arithmetic is not used?

From my understanding, if you add the two hex values normally, you get `F0A17F12`, but how would I add this using MMX instruction for both the packed byte and word?

Comment: Is there some reason why it has to be MMX ? Since you just have two 32 bit values it would probably be easier to use [SWAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR) for this.

Comment: The question is from my textbook, and it stated to use MMX instruction.

Comment: You might want to throw that book out (MMX has been obsolete for 20 years) and get something a bit more up-to-date. If it's for school though and you have no choice then look at the MMX intrinsics [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=MMX), particularly `_mm_add_pi8` and `_mm_add_pi16`.

Comment: unfortunately, it is for school, so i cant throw it out :)

Comment: Do you need to write actual code for this or do you just need to say what the result would be in each case ?

Comment: I believe I need to show my work, but i need the results

Comment: OK - so pretty simple then - is there a particular aspect of this that you're stuck on ?

Comment: Well, i know how to add the hex normally, but im not sure how i would show it using MMX code and for each of the packet

Comment: OK - just break each 32 bit value up into bytes or words and then add each corresponding pair of bytes or words and ignore any carries.

Comment: ok so for the byte, i divide the hex into 8 parts and the word into 2 correct?  and without the carry, for example F + F = E right instead 1E?

Comment: You have 32-bit values, so every one contains 4 bytes or 2 words. MMX register is 64-bit though.

Comment: As @MBo says, each byte corresponds to two hex digits, so you need to start by adding `C2` and `50` for the byte case, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you can get them into MMX registers.

This adds them as if they were double numbers

```
paddd mm0, mm1
```

This adds them as if they were bytes

```
paddb mm0, mm1
```